# How often should I refresh data (by http request) in Android?

Tags: android, httprequest, retrofit

I have to repeatedly make http requests to REST API in order to refresh my data. How often should I make requests? I want to have as fresh data as possible but I also don't want to make refresh every half of a second. Is there any best practice?

Comment: What about server sending you an event via Firebase messaging as soon as an update happens?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible solutions:

- Add support for the if-modified-since header to your api which decreases the bandwidth, but not the amount of requests.
- Add a refresh button and refresh manually when needed
- Use sockets instead of http requests
- Use something like Firebase messaging (as [azizbekian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083957/azizbekian) mentioned) to tell your app to reload the data or even push the data directly.

Comment: Something like firebase messaging looks like good solution for me! But most of the things I found were about push notifications :( can you tell me were I can find how to trigger function in android app using FCM?

Comment: You can send a push notification to the app when new data arrives at the server. Info about integrating push notifications via firebase can be found at https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience. You can call your function from with the onMessageReceived callback.

Comment: So at every refresh user will get push notification? I in that case, it's not good solution for me.

Comment: If the app is opened when the notification arrives, you can catch the notification and it isn't shown to the user. If the app is closed and a notification is sent, then the users does indeed see the notification.